# intelliJ hibernate generate pojo from existing hbm files

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, code-generation, hbm

I'm trying to switch over to intelliJ from eclipse. Back in eclipse, I created a number of hbm (mapping) files which are highly modified. They do things like cause the generated classes to extend from a parent, to implement interfaces, and a number of other customizations.

I have noticed the the intellij process for generating pojos (Generate Persistence Mapping) also generates hbm files. However, I cannot figure out how to instruct intellij to just use the hbm files I already have.

Comment: Hey did you get anywhere with this? I'm in the same situation. It looks like this is the only way https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/import-database-schema-import-mappings.html

Comment: I'm afraid I gave up. Still using eclipse. Maybe I'll try intellij again in a year or two to see if they have improved their hibernate support or perhaps someone will give us a really useful answer.